# How to create sub projects in Play Framework? (play#play-java_2.9.2;2.1-RC3: not found)

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I want to test how sub projects work, especially how the `routes` of the sub project are taken into account in main project ([this was not visible before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424611/playframework-2-0-subproject-and-routes)).

I have read the docs here:
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/SBTSubProjects

What have I done: (after downloading play 2.1 RC3)

1. Create new Java Project: `play new MainProject`
2. Create new folder inside MainProject: `modules`
3. Create new Java Project: `play new SubProject`

On both projects: `play eclipse` since `play eclipsify` does not work anymore

In the main projects `Build.scala` file:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "MainProject"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean 
  )

  val subProject = Project("subproject", file("modules/SubProject"))

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
  ).dependsOn(subProject)

}
```

Now, in the main project I run:

```
play run
```

And I get the following errors:

```
[error] (MainProject/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#play_2.9.2;2.1-RC3: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: play#play-java_2.9.2;2.1-RC3: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: play#play-java-jdbc_2.9.2;2.1-RC3: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: play#play-java-ebean_2.9.2;2.1-RC3: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: play#play-test_2.9.2;2.1-RC3: not found
```

*Note*
I have tried to delete the `Build.scala` from the subproject but I kep getting this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you write the structure of your project? I have done exactly same as described in the link [SBTSunProjects](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/SBTSubProjects). But I'm getting the above listed errors.

Comment: This weekend I will try to do that, both for Scala and Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally got it working:

- You do not have to delete the `Build.scala` from the subproject.

You need to rename the routes file of your sub project. In my example, to `subProject.routes`. If you want to run your subproject in isolation you need to declare that routes must resolve to your subProject.routes. So add this in the `application.conf` of your subProject:

```
application.router=subProject.Routes
```

In your main project, you need to import the routes from the subproject:

```
->  /subProject               subProject.Routes
```

And the build file of the main project should look something like: example is from SCALA but s

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "MainProject"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
   javaCore,
   javaJdbc,
   javaEbean 
  )

  val subProject = play.Project(
    appName + "-subProject", appVersion, path = file("modules/SubProject")
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
  ).dependsOn(subProject)

}
```

Comment: Thanks adis! In my case it doesn't find the `subProject` "package" in `subProject.Routes` (in `routes` file). I don't know what have I done wrong.

Comment: @FerranMaylinch Sounds like something I had when my controllers weren't declared within 'controllers.' namespace. Seems they have to be.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to explicitly set the scala version to 2.10.0 because the subprojects caused a conflict with 2.9.2.

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
)
```

Example taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365406/sbt-failed-to-precise-play-2-apps-project-dependency).